# Facebook Sharer URL via app id and Phonegap

Tags: jquery, facebook, cordova

I saw an example online about using the sharer.php page that facebook allows can I also track who uses this via the APPID in the facebook developer app section.

Here is my example.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fb', function(e) {
    window.open.href = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + encodeURIComponent('this is a title') + '&p[summary]=' + encodeURIComponent('description here') + '&p[url]=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.nufc.com') + '&p[images][0]=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.somedomain.com/image.jpg')
});
```

Comment: I don't believe this works in iOS 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving an error when you try this?

Be sure to whitelist all the servers you are accessing.  I believe you can open it to everything for testing.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html